# htmlentities is not working with json encoding

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know what is going on with this but htmlentities() function is not working!

Here is what i have done

(the bottom code work correctly but htmlentities() does not convert quotes to html code! for example " should be change to some html5 code!

```
$term = "'" . addslashes($_GET['search_term']) . "%'";
if(!isset($term{2})){
    exit();
}

$query = $db->query('SELECT customerID, fullName, dID, birthYear, homeAddress, ID, DATE_FORMAT(idIssue, "%d-%m-%Y") AS idIssue, DATE_FORMAT(idExp, "%d-%m-%Y") AS idExp, phone
                     FROM customers WHERE (fullName LIKE '.$term.' ) LIMIT 0,10');



while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        $arr[$key] = htmlentities(stripslashes($value), ENT_QUOTES);
    }
    $json[] = $arr;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Don't use `addslashes()` for sql parameter sanitization, use prepared statements. Also, drop the `htmlentities()` and `stripslashes()` altogether, let JavaScript do the proper HTML escaping.

Comment: @Jack, wouldn't all of the work to the parser on the receiving end when some of it can be handled on the server side. Drop the stripslashes, it's not necessary. Keep the htmlentities, it's helpful, especially where some browsers may have trouble with character encoding. Also, plain `"` are absolutely fine. htmlentities takes care of the strange characters.

Comment: @Austin It shouldn't be the concern of PHP to know what the values are going to be used for; for all we know, at some point you may want to use the raw values in JavaScript (e.g. to make another Ajax request).

Comment: You can also use the json_encode function with an extra parameter to encode the quotes http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you pass to json_encode() must be UTF-8 encoded data.
Therefore, before you run `json_encode`, use `utf8_encode`.

Example:

```
 $arr[$key] = htmlentities(stripslashes(utf8_encode($value)), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Is this legitimately the best way to get useable JSON data from PHP? You have to run utf8_encode(), stripslashes(), htmlentities() AND json_encode()? I keep getting issues with data which is human entered and each time I add another layer of escape function...

Comment: @php-b-grader no it depends on your use case and the type of data you try to encode. Normally it should not be as involved as here.